# Google Maps Location Selection

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on creating a tool to select a place via Google Maps API. This part is simple and I have no problems with it, but it is too specific. I want to do something similar to [this](http://www.usnaviguide.com/v3maps/WhatZipCode.htm?lat=37&lng=-122), but need to accommodate the entire world, not just zip codes.

I would think the same effect should be able to be achieved by the highlighting an administrative level. Does this require KML file, and if so can anyone through a provider that might have this level of detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get administrative boundaries for the world here http://www.gadm.org/ or here http://www.unsalb.org/. You will not be able to achieve this with a single KML file  though, as this would be one big file (I am talking about at least four hundred MB and there is a 4MB limit for KML files on Maps).

You will need to store the data in the db and pull out only relevant boundaries and draw them as polygons on the map. In other words it sounds like you might need a GIS server(open or ArcGis). Although you could build it from scratch using any geo-enabled db such as mySQL or MSSQL.